# Jquery Autocomplete in mvc if user types text which is not in autocomplete list

Tags: jquery-ui

```
Jquery Autocomplete UI in mvc .. If user enter some text which is not in list it should alert not in list ....
```

In View:-

```
 $("#loc").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/a/AutoLoc",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.length == 0) {
                                alert('Please select an item from the list');
                                document.getElementById('Loc').value = "";
                                document.getElementById('Loc').focus();
                                document.getElementById('Loc').style.border = "solid 1px red";

                            }
                            else

                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                document.getElementById('Location').style.border = "solid 1px black";
                                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.LocationId };
                            }));





                        }
                    })
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#locationID").val(ui.item.id);

                }

            });
```

**in Controller:**

```
 public JsonResult AutoLoc(string term)
    {
        var result = (from r in db.S
                      where r.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                      select new { r.Name, r.id }).Distinct();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here suppose we enter 'a' then it will not alert any message . Though 'a' is not in list
when we enter any character which is not in autocomplete list it should alert and make that box as red.

Actually What is happening in 'data' we are getting values because in controller we are writing a query as contains or startwith 'a' so value is returned but as a individual 'a' is not in list that starts with or contains 'a'.

Comment: so the normal functionality is working fine ?

Comment: yes but when we enter 'a' and leave it without selecting from autocomplete list  it will not alert and make that box red

Comment: what is the json format you are you are returning

Comment: i am returning an object which contains id and name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In View:

```
$("#loc").autocomplete({    
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/a/AutoLoc",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                var found = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.LocationId};
                });


                }
            });
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {                
            var referenceValue = $(this).val();
            var matches = false;

            $(".ui-autocomplete li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == referenceValue) {
                    matches = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (!matches) {
                alert('Please select an item from the list');
                this.value = "";
                this.focus();
                this.style.border = "solid 1px red";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("submitbutton").disabled = false;
                this.style.border = "solid 1px black";
            }
        }



    });
```

Now when we type 'a' it will alert and show the box border in red color......
This is what i wanted....

Comment: Then accept your answer. you were not clear with your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#loc").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/a/AutoLoc",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                var found = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.LocationId};
                });
                if (found.length === 0) {
                    alert('Please select an item from the list');
                    $("#loc").val("");
                    $('#loc').focus();
                    $('#loc').css("border", "solid 1px red");
                } else {
                    $('#loc').css("border", "none");
                }
                response(found);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#locationID").val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not going into response block

Comment: i modified the code. please check if its same which you are using

Comment: yes i modified it but again it is not working and in console also no error

Comment: Thanks.Actually What is happening in 'found' we are getting values because in controller we are writing a query as contains or startwith 'a' so value is returned but as a individual 'a' is not in list that starts with or contains 'a'.        Am i clear to you.

Comment: can you post your json which is return when you pass `a`